# ¿Cómo puedo restar elementos de un array sucesivamente?

Tags: python, array, numpy, datos

¿Alguien de ustedes me puede indicar cómo puedo restar sucesivamente los datos almacenados en un array generado por medio de un ciclo `for`?

Es decir:

1. Primero indico el número de elementos que voy a iterar:

```
ND=float(input(" Ingrese número de nodos"))
```

2. Elaboro una lista vacía denotada como:

```
X=[]
```

3. Procedo a generar el ciclo for:

```
for N in range (0, ND):

   x=float(input("Ingrese coordenada"))
   X.append(x)
```

4. Procedo a convertir la lista inicial en un array:

```
X=np.array(X)
```

Ahora, ¿Cómo puedo restar los elementos almacenados en el array?

Ejemplo del programa a elaborar:

1. Número de nodos: 3
2. Coordenada: 0
3. Coordenada: 450
4. Coordenada: 600

X=[0,450,600]

"RESULTADO A ESPERAR"

LONGITUD=[(450-0), (600-450)]
LONGITUD=[450,150]

No se si me puedan colaborar.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola Robert, bienvenido, te sugiero que edites tu pregunta, elimines las imágenes y agregues tu código como texto, para evitar recibir votos negativos, mira [Cómo preguntar](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida, obtengas una mejor respuesta, evitar votos negativos y/o que tu pregunta sea eliminada.

aprovecha y haz el recorrido de [Bienvenida](https://es.stackoverflow.com/tour) para entender mejor cómo funcionamos y de paso obtener una medalla!.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Buen día,

La librería `numpy` tiene la función [`numpy.diff`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.diff.html) que hace lo que deseas.

Ejemplo genérico:

```
import numpy as np

# Declaramos el array
a = np.array([0, 450, 600])

# Imprimimos la diferencia
print(np.diff(a))
```

Esto imprime:

```
[450, 150]
```

Y puedes acceder a cada valor con el índice, por ejemplo:

```
b = np.diff(a)
print(b[0])
```

Esto imprime `450`.

Comment: Listo amigo muchas gracias. Sera que me puede aclarar otra duda? Quiero crear una variable que resulte de multiplicar L=12X/[450 , 150] pero que los valores me aparezcan por separado. Es decir, L1=12x/450, L2=12x/150.  Que comando se utiliza?

Comment: Por que por ejemplo, cuando corro el programa las respuesta me aparecen [40528. 1215.]. Pero me gustaría saber como obtener los valores por separados.

Comment: Buen día, no es muy claro lo que deseas hacer, ¿Qué significa `x/`? Si aún necesitas ayuda con eso te recomiendo crear una nueva pregunta para mantener una sola pregunta por publicación. Saludos